# How to copy a range of elements in RDD into a smaller RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD[String]:

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(Seq("paul", "jim,", "joe", "mary", "sean", "peter", "lucy"))
```

What I would like to be able to do is to generate a smallerRDD by being able to copy a range of lines from the above master rdd into a smaller rdd.

Use case: 
When spinning through RDDs in spark unusual situations can arise, more often than not certain lines/records in RDDs can cause problems.

Being able to programatically copy one to the other use a usefull feature indeed as I could not find a canned rdd method to do this.
see my solution below.

Comment: how would you choose which part of the RDD should be copied to the smaller RDD?

Comment: Please expand on your use case. Yes, certain lines might cause problems but would you really identify by those by index, or  by content?

Answer (score 0):

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(Seq("paul", "jim", "joe", "mary", "sean", "peter", "lucy")) 

val startIndex = 1
val endIndex = 5
val shortRdd=rdd.zipWithIndex().filter { case (_, idx) => idx >= startIndex && idx <= endIndex }.map(p=>p._1)
shortRdd.count
shortRdd.foreach(println)
```

Step1: Lets see whats inside the RDD:

```
rdd.foreach(println)
peter
lucy
jim
joe
paul
mary
sean
```

Step2: Apply a transformation to append index, notice the an index value is now applied to each line.

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().foreach(println)
(peter,5)
(jim,1)
(joe,2)
(paul,0)
(mary,3)
(sean,4)
(lucy,6)
```

Step3: Apply filters on the index position, pull indexes between start and end index position

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter { case (_, idx) => idx >= startIndex && idx <= endIndex }.foreach(println)
(mary,3)
(sean,4)
(jim,1)
(peter,5)
(joe,2)
```

Step4: Map back to single element in each line

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter { case (_, idx) => idx >= startIndex && idx <= endIndex }.map(p=>p._1).foreach(println)
mary
jim
joe
peter
sean
```

I performed this process on RDD with lines of 100k or more without any issues. Let me know how this performs with larger RDD.

Thats it! Paul.